# Parse xml and store into mysql table in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, dom

I have written the code that retrieves the data from XML file using *xml.etree*. Is there any best way to store the data into database by parsing an XML file.

My code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import mysql.connector

dom = ElementTree.parse('profile.xml')

ticker = dom.findall('TICKER')
name = dom.findall('NAME')
address = dom.findall('ADDRESS')
phone = dom.findall('PHONE')
website = dom.findall('WEBSITE')
sector = dom.findall('SECTOR')
industry = dom.findall('INDUSTRY')
full_time = dom.findall('FULL_TIME')
bus_summ = dom.findall('BUS_SUMM')

ticker_list = [t.text for t in ticker]
name_list = [t.text for t in name]
add_list = [t.text for t in address]
phn_list = [t.text for t in phone]
site_list = [t.text for t in website]
sec_list = [t.text for t in sector]
ind_list = [t.text for t in industry]
emp_list = [t.text for t in full_time]
sum_list = [t.text for t in bus_summ]

db = mysql.connector.Connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', password ='root' , database = 'nldb_project')
cur = db.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO profiles(`prof_ticker`,`name`,`address`,`phonenum`,`website`,`sector`,`industry`,full_time`,`bus_summ`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

sqltuples = [(t,n,a,p,s,sec,i,e,su) for t,n,a,p,s,sec,i,e,su in zip(ticker_list,name_list,add_list,phn_list,site_list,sec_list,ind_list,emp_list,sum_list)]
cur.executemany(query,sqltuples)
```

I am using python 3.6.5 version.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<collection shelf = 'profile'>
<INFO>
    <TICKER>AAPL</TICKER>
    <NAME> Apple Inc.</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>1 Infinite Loop;Cupertino, CA 95014;United State</ADDRESS>
    <PHONE>408-996-1010</PHONE>
    <WEBSITE>http://www.apple.com</WEBSITE>
    <SECTOR>Technology</SECTOR>
    <INDUSTRY>Consumer Electronics</INDUSTRY>
    <FULL_TIME>100,000</FULL_TIME>
    <BUS_SUMM>Apple</BUS_SUMM>
    <SOURCE>https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL</SOURCE> 
</INFO>
<INFO>
    <TICKER>T</TICKER>
    <NAME> AT and T Inc.</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>208 South Akard Street;Dallas, TX 75202;United States</ADDRESS>
    <PHONE>210-821-4105</PHONE>
    <WEBSITE>http://www.att.com</WEBSITE>
    <SECTOR>Communication Services</SECTOR>
    <INDUSTRY> Telecom Services</INDUSTRY>
    <FULL_TIME>254,000</FULL_TIME>
    <BUS_SUMM>at and t</BUS_SUMM>
    <SOURCE>https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/T/profile?p=T</SOURCE>
</INFO>
<INFO>
    <TICKER>IBM</TICKER>
    <NAME>International Business Machines Corporation</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>1 New Orchard Road;Armonk, NY 10504;United States</ADDRESS>
    <PHONE>914-499-1900</PHONE>
    <WEBSITE>http://www.ibm.com</WEBSITE>
    <SECTOR>Technology</SECTOR>
    <INDUSTRY> Information Technology Services</INDUSTRY>
    <FULL_TIME>366,600</FULL_TIME>
    <BUS_SUMM>ibm</BUS_SUMM>
    <SOURCE>https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM/profile?p=IBM</SOURCE>
</INFO>
<INFO>
    <TICKER>TWTR</TICKER>
    <NAME>Twitter,Inc.</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>1355 Market Street;Suite 900;San Francisco, CA 94103;United States</ADDRESS>
    <PHONE>415-222-9670</PHONE>
    <WEBSITE>http://www.twitter.com</WEBSITE>
    <SECTOR>Technology</SECTOR>
    <INDUSTRY>Internet Content Information</INDUSTRY>
    <FULL_TIME>3,372</FULL_TIME>
    <BUS_SUMM>twitter</BUS_SUMM>
    <SOURCE>https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TWTR/profile?p=TWTR</SOURCE>
</INFO>
<INFO>
    <TICKER>TSLA</TICKER>
    <NAME>Tesla,Inc.</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>3500 Deer Creek Road;Palo Alto, CA 94304;United States</ADDRESS>
    <PHONE>650-681-5000</PHONE>
    <WEBSITE>http://www.tesla.com</WEBSITE>
    <SECTOR>Consumer Cyclical</SECTOR>
    <INDUSTRY>Auto Manufacturers</INDUSTRY>
    <FULL_TIME>37,543</FULL_TIME>
    <BUS_SUMM>tesla</BUS_SUMM>
    <SOURCE>https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/profile?p=TSLA</SOURCE>
</INFO>
<INFO>
    <TICKER>PYPL</TICKER>
    <NAME>PayPal Holdings, Inc.</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>2211 North First Street;San Jose, CA 95131;United States</ADDRESS>
    <PHONE>408-967-1000</PHONE>
    <WEBSITE>http://www.paypal.com</WEBSITE>
    <SECTOR>Financial Services</SECTOR>
    <INDUSTRY>Credit Services</INDUSTRY>
    <FULL_TIME>18,700</FULL_TIME>
    <BUS_SUMM>paypal</BUS_SUMM>
    <SOURCE>https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PYPL/profile?p=PYPL</SOURCE>
</INFO>
</collection>
```

Comment: It is impossible that your code works.

Comment: Have you even checked how [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) works?

Comment: It doesn't show any error but is not entering into the database. @Begueradj

Comment: @band_cherry You most likely want to use [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) instead of `findall`. If the change makes the code work as intended, please [edit] it in so we can make meaningful review.

Comment: Does the code function correctly?  If not, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.  If you've tested it, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test your code but there's a big block of copy-paste only to generate the arguments to pass to `zip`.

So the alternative is to generate the arguments "anonymously" from the tag names only, and pass to zip using argument unpacking.

(changed from comments: `findall` => `iter`)

Also, no need to unpack the arguments just to pass them exactly as-is in the `zip` loop. Just convert the result of `zip` to a `list`

Here's a much shorter version of your code. If you add more tags, you just have one item to add in the tag list & in the query now:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import mysql.connector

dom = ElementTree.parse('profile.xml')

# compose the argument list in one line, drop the big copied/pasted block
args_list = ([t.text for t in dom.iter(tag)] for tag in ['TICKER','NAME','ADDRESS','PHONE','WEBSITE','SECTOR','INDUSTRY','FULL_TIME','BUS_SUMM'])

# db connection code is unchanged
db = mysql.connector.Connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', password ='root' , database = 'nldb_project')
cur = db.cursor()
# this part could be optimized with a dictionary to relate to the tag names
query = "INSERT INTO profiles(`prof_ticker`,`name`,`address`,`phonenum`,`website`,`sector`,`industry`,full_time`,`bus_summ`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

# create the tuples from the argument list
sqltuples = list(zip(*args_list))

# execute query (unchanged)
cur.executemany(query,sqltuples)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for providing me the useful information by making the code simpler.